# How to write table alias in ActiveRecord in yii2

Tags: yii2

I have a sql query like below -

```
SELECT 
district, coalesce(sell.sale,0) as totalsale 
FROM `districts` 
left join 
(SELECT parties_district, billdate, sum(billamount) as sale FROM `bills` left join parties on bills.bills_partyname = parties.parties_partyname group by parties_district) as sell 
on sell.parties_district = districts.district
```

So far I've written the query till -

```
SELECT 
parties_district, billdate, sum(billamount) as sale 
FROM `bills` 
left join parties 
on bills.bills_partyname = parties.parties_partyname 
group by parties_district
```

And my query in yii2 ActiveRecord looks like -

```
$query = Parties::find()
->select(['parties_district','parties_partyname','sum(billamount) as sale'])
->joinWith('bills')
->groupby('parties_district');
```

Please tell me how can I write the whole query. I think I'm stuck with the alias part and there is a subquery in it. Please tell me how can I write a subquery within a query.

I've tried -

```
$subQuery = Parties::find()->select(['parties_district','parties_partyname','sum(billamount) as sale'])->joinWith('bills sell')->groupby('parties_district');
        $query = Districts::find()->select(['district','coalesce(sell.sale,0) as totalsale'])->leftJoin('$subQuery', 'sell.parties_district = districts.district');
        $models = $query->all();
```

but getting the following error

```
Database Exception – yii\db\Exception
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'gm.$subquery' doesn't exist
The SQL being executed was: SELECT `district`, coalesce(sell.sale,0) as totalsale FROM `districts` LEFT JOIN `$subQuery` ON sell.parties_district = districts.district

Error Info: Array
(
    [0] => 42S02
    [1] => 1146
    [2] => Table 'gm.$subquery' doesn't exist
)

↵
Caused by: PDOException
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'gm.$subquery' doesn't exist
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out the answer. Thanks to this page - www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-query-builder.html. 
It will be like below -

```
$subQuery1 = (new Query())->select(['parties_district','billdate','sum(billamount) as sale'])->from ('bills')->join('LEFT JOIN','parties','bills.bills_partyname = parties.parties_partyname')->groupby('parties_district')->where('billdate != "NULL"');
$query = (new Query())->select(['district','coalesce(sell.sale,0) as totalsale'])->from('districts')->leftJoin(['sell' => $subQuery1],'sell.parties_district = districts.district');
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case is better use a literal notation for select content (and not hash notation) this way

```
$query = Parties::find()
->select('parties_district, parties_partyname, sum(billamount) as sale'])
->joinWith('bills')
 ->groupby('parties_district');
```

and for more complex query use findBySql Query

```
$sql = "SELECT 
        district, coalesce(sell.sale,0) as totalsale 
        FROM `districts` 
        left join 
        (SELECT parties_district, billdate, sum(billamount) as sale 
           FROM `bills` left join parties 
                  on bills.bills_partyname = parties.parties_partyname 
        group by parties_district) as sell 
           on sell.parties_district = districts.district"

$model = Districts::findBySql($sql)->all();
```

Comment: That part is fine. I've joined parties table with bills table perfectly. Now what I want is to join this query with the district table. I want to know how can I do that. Please have a look at the sql query at the top of the question. I've edited the question as well.

Comment: @Tanmy is not fair change the question .. .. if my question is right (respect to you original questio) please mark it as accepted, post a new question properly and eventually comment me with the new question link

Comment: I didn't change the original question. What I've done is that I've tried to solve it. Which I've given after I've tried part - and has given the error message. The solution you posted above was already written in the question in the first hand. Please have a look. Appreciate your honest effort, but I elaborated my question in the above comment. Please have a look.

Comment: @I'm sorry .. I'm looking to more than a question and so ..  i take a look

Comment: You've helped me many times earlier. It's not a problem at all.

Comment: I have update the answer with a suggestionn  .. if this is not what you are looking for .. tell me so i remove the answer and you can let the post free for others